# заполнение django формы

Tags: python, html, django

Имеется вот такое поле в моей модели:

```
number_out = models.CharField("№ исх.", max_length=64, default='')
```

forms.py:

```
class NewEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['number_out', 'to_whom', 'what', 'executor']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

внутри html шаблона оно рендеридтся следующим образом:

```
<li class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="{{ form.number_out.id_for_label }}">№ Исх.:</label>
    {{ form.number_out }}
    {{ form.number_out.errors }}
    </li>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как бы мне прямо внутри html вставить в это поле некоторую строку. Услово, я хочу туда вставить строку "тест".

Пробовал делать так:

```
{{ form.number_out.value }} {{"тест"}}
```

но строка "тест" появляется рядом с текстовым полем справа, не внутри него, как мне нужно.

при этом, мне не нужно, чтобы она вставлялась туда через default, тк внутри html я буду заполнять его значением по умолчанию в зависимости от некоторых условий. Про сами условия и тд вопросов нет, я разобрался. Но вот как вставить строчку в поле - никак не соображу

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте виджеты и атрибут `value`

```
class NewEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    number_out= forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value' :'number_out'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['number_out', 'to_whom', 'what', 'executor']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

или я не правильно понял куда надо вставить текст

Comment: Спасибо! Поняли Вы правильно, именно в это поле мне и нужно вставить некоторый текст. Но есть ли возможность сделать такую операцию внутри html шаблона?

Comment: @i_suxarev если ответ вам помог справа от ответ есть галочка)

Comment: я знаю :) Но пока ещё не работает, так как нужно. Я понимаю, как можно в скрипте вставить нужное значение в поле, но как это сделать в именно в шаблоне...

Comment: @i_suxarev а как нужно?)

Comment: да я ж говорю: вот в шаблоне это поле выглядит так: '{{ form.number_out }}'. Как мне изменить его содержимое именно в html шаблоне? Должен же быть способ. То есть чтобы при открытии страницы с этим шаблоном, строка "тест" попала в  '{{ form.number_out }}'. И именно через html

Comment: Всё, я вроде разобрался :) Нужно было, как Вы посоветовали, создать виджет для этого поля в forms.py, а потом уже в html  я сделал так '<input id="number_out" type="text" name="number_out" value="тестовое">'. И вроде всё заработало, как я и хотел )